# How to find a file with not match string using select-string in PowerShell?

Tags: string, powershell, file

I have a lot of file. I want to find the file which is not contain of a string.
I try this, but it return duplicate file name.

```
$File = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\*.txt"
$Result = Select-String -Pattern "Identifier -NotMatch $File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FileName
Write-Host "Result: $Result"
```

It return like this

```
1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 1589.txt 158A.txt 158A.txt 158A.txt 158A.txt 158A.txt 158A.txt AB8A.txt AB8A.txt AB8A.txt AB8A.txt AB8A.txt
```

Anyone can help please. Thank you

Comment: Are you asking about the file content or the file name? If it's the latter you should use `Get-ChildItem` instead of `Select-String`.

Comment: I need the file name @Olaf. I already use Get-Childitem, but that is the result

Comment: @SBR - your `Select-String` call is not valid. have you tried to run just that bit of code?

Comment: @SBR - also, do you want the `Select-String` to work on the file NAME or on the _content_ of the file?

Comment: I want the select-string work on the content. I want to search the content of file which not match with pattern and get the file name

Comment: My expectation, I can get the file name which not contain of the pattern

Answer (score 0):

`-NotMatch` will make `Select-String` return the *lines* that don't match, it doesn't work at the file level.

To do what you want, run ALL the files through `Select-String` and then filter out those that have any matches:

```
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path D:\ -Filter *.txt |Where-Object {
  @($_ |Select-String -Pattern "Identifier" |Select-Object -First 1).Count -eq 0
} |Select-Object -ExpandProperty FileName
```

We grab the first possible match from the file in question - if none is found, the array expression will be empty and `Count -eq 0`